# REST API error middlename,suffix,informalname fields do not exist but they appear in describe results

Tags: rest-api, describefieldresult

We develop a AppExchange package and are having an issue with `middlename,suffix,informalname` fields on the `Contact` object. The issue is these fields are returned through a describe call also filtering by `isAccessible() == true`. This list of fields is then sent to javascript which generates a REST query which returns an error `invalid field` for these. I'm assuming the issue is they are simply not enabled. Is there a way to determine through the describe information if these fields are enabled in the org?

Notes:

- The API version for the class and REST call are V38
- We have to handle the scenario where these fields are either enabled and disabled in the customer org

### **UPDATE:**

Our javascript (in mobile app) calls the apex REST endpoint (endpoint and helper class both on API V38) and it returns `middlename,suffix,informalname` using code as follows:

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fldsMap = thisObj.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            for (Schema.SObjectField sf : fldsMap.values()) 
            {
                DescribeFieldResult sfdescr = sf.getDescribe();

                if (sfdescr.isAccessible()) {
                    FieldDescWrapper resWrapper = new FieldDescWrapper();
                    resWrapper.name = sfdescr.getName();

                    String objName = sfdescr.getRelationshipName();

                    if(objName != null && (objName.contains('__c') || Ctl_RelationshipBuilder.whiteListedStandardObjects.contains(objName))) {
                        resWrapper.relLookup = objName+'.'+Util.returnNameFieldForObject(objName,false);
                    } else {
                        resWrapper.relLookup = null;
                    }

                    result.add(resWrapper);
                }
            }
```

If I run the following code in anon. apex I do NOT get the `middlename,suffix,informalname` fields.

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> contactFieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (Schema.sobjectfield field : contactFieldMap.values()) {
            System.debug('field val : ' + field.getDescribe().getname());
        }
```

I've also tried running the above code in a VF page/controller with API versions of both set to V38 to eliminate any oddities from the anon. apex running in V41)

Outstanding questions:

1. Why are these fields returning at all when they're not enabled in this org?
2. Why are they only returning ONLY in the context of the REST endpoint ONLY in this org?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Middlenames were added in Spring 15: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_general_middle_name_suffix_enable.htm

Comment: @battery.cord this doesn't seem to happen in every org, working on it.

Comment: @cropredy yes, but they still need to be enabled under `customize => user interface`